# How can I get Java date in another Language

Tags: java

I am living in Austria and if I print the date in Java I get in the german format. But I want to have it in the english format.

I already tried it with the following code.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.*;
public class Calendar extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date currentDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy", Locale.UK);
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(currentDate));
```

Comment: For me, your code prints `Wed, 15 May 2019`  and when I change the locale to `Locale.GERMAN` it prints `Mi, 15 Mai 2019`. Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: For me too, the code works fine.

Comment: java.util.Date is a terrible, terrible class. https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

Never use `Date` & `SimpleDateFormat`. Supplanted years ago by *java.time* classes.

Time zone is crucial to determining current date.

Let `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` automatically localize.

```
LocalDate
.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Vienna ) 
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL )
    .withLocale( Locale.UK )
)
```

> Wednesday, 15 May 2019

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Ditto for [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) & [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

### Localize

The `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalize…` methods will automatically localize for you, choosing the appropriate format as well as translating name of day-of-week & month etc.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

  - The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
  - The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.UK ;   // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH, Locale.JAPAN, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.LONG )
    .withLocale( l )
;
String output = localDate.format( f );
```

> output: Wednesday, 15 May 2019

Alternatively, define your own custom formatting pattern using [`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale)). Pass the optional `Locale` argument, to determine localization. [Search Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern%20java&t=osx&ia=web), as this has been covered many times. And see [this other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56149872/642706) on this page by Gaurav Shakya.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Basil, great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use This: Java 8

```
LocalDate localDate=LocalDate.now();

String dateInGerman=localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, dd MMMM, yyyy",Locale.GERMANY));
```

Comment: If I try to run it like this I get this error:                                                                                           Calendar.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy", Locale.UK);
                                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable Locale
  location: class Calendar

Comment: @max Bauer, try above code if you are using java 8 version, working fine.

Comment: I am not getting any error in your code.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is interested:
The code runs now. I have just imported "java.util.Locale"
Nevertheless thanks for you help

Comment: Meaning the original code gave you a compilation error, but you never mentioned this or posted the error message in your question, making the question impossible to answer correctly.